# Does pagination actually ease the stress on mongodb? If yes, what is the best way to achieve it using mongoose and nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I think the question is pretty straight forward. Am loading certain blogs from my database and I thought pagination would help navigation plus maybe decrease stress on server. I saw people using functions like **skip()** and **limit()**. But I also saw people saying how it just increases the load on server as it has to sort more thoroughly. So just wanted to know whats it exactly.

Comment: Any extra operation is going to cause an extra load on the server, but on the other side of things you should try and minimize server payloads to the client which pagination helps to achieve. There's no one-case answer, you should focus on balancing your metrics

Comment: @rantao well thanks for that reply. I was very dicey about using it but i'll go for it now. Btw, for a GET method, I only know **lean()** to be an optimizing function. Is there anything else to achieve balancing of metrics ?

Comment: Your best best would probably to check off [these](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/optimize-query-performance-with-indexes-and-projections/) boxes if you haven't already